# is there any way to write (for len-1 in A:) in python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Hi I am new in python coding. I am using for loop for a matrix. It is working fine when am using

For len in A:

It runs equal to the number of rows in matrix.

But I am using 0 index for my purpose so I want to use len minus 1 (len-1).

So is there any way to use len-1 in for loop. Because when am writing len-1 in for loop it is showing error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing what you managed to make work, and give a small, well chosen example of what you are trying to accomplish. You question is really unclear without that.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to use enumerate() when working with indexes, like this:

```
for index, row in enumerate(A):
    # do something
```

So if you want to make len - 1, just do this:

```
for index, row in enumerate(A[:-1]):
    # do something
```

Python lists have negative indexes, so A[:-1] means take all values before index -1 (the last one)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
For i in range(len(A)):
```

Because if you run the following code

```
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for i in A:
    print(len)
```

it will give the output as:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

but if you run the following code:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    print(len)
```

it prints out:

```
0
1
2
```

So, you can perform mathematical operations (+, -, *, /).

Comment: ... and see how you can't use the builtin `len` function anymore after that, because `len` is now a number...

Comment: Yes Absolutely, try to avoid **build in function/methods** as a variable!